# Modify html page on reverse proxy with "higher logic"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a problem where I currently dont know how to solve it: In a backend structure is a server which delivers html webpages which should be send to the client. A classic reverse proxy (like nginx) can handle this problem very easy.

In this case the website must be changed before they is send to the client. But not in the easy way like `ngx_http_sub_module` that allows.

There are some additional information in the website (e.g. a json object as a html comment). These information are necessary to modify the website in the correct way.

A invented example:

The website contains this json:

```
environment = {"user": "admin"}
```

Additional to that this condition:

```
<!-- if(user == "admin") -->
<strong>Hello Admin!</strong>
<!-- end; -->
```

The task of the "advanced" reverse proxy is to understand the environment, evaluation the conditions and remove content which does not met the condition(s). And the "meta information" also.

It is not possible to change the problematic backend system which generates this pages. Unfortunately...

At this point of my research I found no reverse proxy which can handle this task. Rewriting http header is no problem for the most proxies but content on such a "high" level is a problem. Currently I'm at the point that I will write my one reverse proxy with PHP (and nginx) or node.js to solve this problem.

However, I can hardly imagine that I am the first with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you have different options to solve the problem, I would list the two I can think of

**A middleware proxy code**

So you will write a PHP, Python or NodeJS which Nginx will send the request to, this will query the existing backend and process and the output and return.

**Nginx with Lua Scripting**

You can install custom Nginx installed with Lua Scripting capabilities. Openresty is one which comes with all these custom addon pre-installed. Then you create a config like below

```
location /apiOld {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://oldapi;
}

location /api {
    content_by_lua_file parse_response.lua;
}
```

In the lua file you will have something like below

```
local res = ngx.location.capture("/apiOld");
local body = res.body
local cjson = require("cjson")
local data = cjson.decode(body)

...do something with data and create desired output...
local result = "desired output"
ngx.say(result)
```

I did something similar for creating a Docker label metadata server, if you want you can have a look at the approach on http://tarunlalwani.com/post/docker-compose-scale-with-dynamic-configuration-part-1/

Comment: This is great! Do you know if this is possible using something other than Lua?